# Decreasing Frames extracted per sec in openCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I want to decrease the frames extracted. Currently the below python script extracts around 30 frames per sec but I want 12-14  frames extracted per sec.

How can I change the code to decrease it?

```
import numpy as np
import os
from glob import glob
import cv2
```

```
def create_dir(path):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError:
        print(f"ERROR: creating directory with name {path}")
```

```
def save_frame(video_path, save_dir):
    name = video_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, name)
    create_dir(save_path)
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    idx=0
    
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        
        if ret==False:
            cap.release()
            break
        
        cv2.imwrite(f"{save_path}/{idx}.png", frame)
        idx += 1
```

```
video_paths = glob("video/*")
save_dir = "frames"
for path in video_paths:
    save_frame(path, save_dir)
```

Comment: Not sure what you really mean... how about discarding every second frame by putting an extra`ret, frame = cap.read()` in your loop - then you'll go from 30fps to 15fps.

Comment: What I mean is, I am extracting a video of 21 secs and this script gives me 650 frames!! Now that creates a lot more redundant frames and information. I only want around 15 frames per second that is 315 frames in total. How to do that? I am new to python and don't really know the behind-the-scenes work in openCV.

Comment: I'm suggesting you discard every second frame, which will give you 325 frames instead of 650. Can you clarify what's wrong with that as a suggestion?

Comment: Oh okay, Now I understand what were u trying to say. You are saying to discard the first frame returned by the read function and to only consider the second frame as the remaining python code will only pick up the second frame.Thanks for the help @Mark Setchell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the frame rate of the camera. It might be able to capture at the requested frame rate.

```
cap = ...
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS, 15)
...
```

Comment: That's a better suggestion than mine - which stemmed from trying a quick-fix to get OP up and running without seeing any initialisation/setup code or really understanding what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the line that reads the frame, then you'll read two frames but save only one. That will result in half the total number of frames:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ret, frame = cap.read()       
    if ret==False:
        cap.release()
        break
    ...
    ...
```